# Rails observer causes slow processing time in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.1, observer-pattern, asset-pipeline

I'm on Rails 3.1.1 and I have noticed my app has become exceedingly slow (15 seconds) in development mode. See my firebug 'Net' listing below:

[image: Before!]

I've done a number of things like:

- reducing the number of gems
- turning class caching on
- turning asset debugging to false
- turning asset compression to true
- installing the rails-dev-boost gem

Maybe there were some improvements, but nothing helped it to go as fast I'd expect when running off localhost. That is, until I commented out my observers config line in `application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.observers = :item_observer, :loan_observer, :friendship_observer, :message_observer, :user_observer
```

And then the app was fast again (~1 sec) load time. See the firebug listing now:

[image: After!]

Other notes:

- When in production on Heroku, it's fast (~1 sec), as you'd expect.
- I'm using postgresql and Thin; I have not tried using other DBs to see if this problem exists.
- When I commented out just the last observer, user_observer, the load time dropped by about half.
- The load times printed in `development.log` do not reflect actual load times. Assets were flagged as 304 Not Modified (0ms) they really took a while to load.
- Yes, I'm using the asset pipeline

**The Golden Question:** Is the simple act of registering observers causing assets to load slowly? And what can be done about it?

Comment: I'd like to add to this question with "are observers considered good practice in rails?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks.

Rails is running all of the to_prepare hooks on every Sprockets asset request in development mode.  This includes things like auto-(re)loading your code, and various gems perform work in there too.  And in your case, observers are being registered (which - I believe - causes Rails to reference a good portion of your app in order to reference the models)

rails-dev-tweaks disables to_prepare & reloading on any asset request (and a few others - read the first part of its README).  Speeds up your dev environment by a huge amount for any decently sized project.  It's also configurable to do this for any additional requests you like

Answer (score 0):

The way I am fixing this is refactoring the observers into concerns. https://gist.github.com/1014971

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I must admit I am not familiar with Concerns... or even a good understanding of when to use Modules, to be honest. Could you point me to some helpful resources on these topics? Many thanks!